# how to have more than one switch?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to have more than one switch on the same page, I succeeded but the problem is that when I click on a switch it modifies all the other switches.

Here is my code

```
const Setting =() => {
    const [switchValue, setSwitchValue] = useState(false);

    const toggleSwitch = (value, nb) => {
        setSwitchValue(value);
  };
    return (
    <View>
        <View style={styles.Container}>
            <Text style={styles.Title}>Change Profil Setting</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.ContainerText}>
            <Text syle={styles.Normal}>Over 18:</Text>
            <Switch
                style={{left: 50}}
                onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                value={switchValue}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.ContainerText}>
            <Text syle={styles.Normal}>AutoPlay:</Text>
            <Switch
                style={{left: 50}}
                onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                value={switchValue}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.ContainerText}>
            <Text syle={styles.Normal}>FlexDirecttion:</Text>
            <Switch
                style={{left: 50}}
                onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                value={switchValue}
            />
        </View>
    </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: All your switches use the same `switchValue`, and the same handler.

Comment: I'm new to js and i don't know how to make each switch have its own id or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Setting =() => {
const [switchValue, setSwitchValue] = useState(false);
const [switch2Value, setSwitch2Value] = useState(false);
const [switch3Value, setSwitch3Value] = useState(false);
const toggleSwitch = (value, nb) => {
    setSwitchValue(value);
};
const toggle2Switch = (value, nb) => {
    setSwitch2Value(value);
};
const toggle3Switch = (value, nb) => {
    setSwitch3Value(value);
};
return (
<View>
    <View style={styles.Container}>
        <Text style={styles.Title}>Change Profil Setting</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.ContainerText}>
        <Text syle={styles.Normal}>Over 18:</Text>
        <Switch
            style={{left: 50}}
            onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
            value={switchValue}
        />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.ContainerText}>
        <Text syle={styles.Normal}>AutoPlay:</Text>
        <Switch
            style={{left: 50}}
            onValueChange={toggle2Switch}
            value={switch2Value}
        />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.ContainerText}>
        <Text syle={styles.Normal}>FlexDirecttion:</Text>
        <Switch
            style={{left: 50}}
            onValueChange={toggle3Switch}
            value={switch3Value}
        />
    </View>
</View>
)
}
```

This can be considered as a work around. What I would suggest is wrap the Switch component inside another component and import it where-ever you want by incorporating the state management in that component.